# Excel: lock sheet, but keep tables expandable

Tags: microsoft-excel

My goal is to protect a sheet, but make users able to edit and add rows to the contained tables.

When I try to protect the sheet with no cells locked, the tables become unable to add rows even though their cells are not locked. I have tried to check all the *Allow all the users of this worksheet to* checkboxes, but it does not help me.

Does anybody know of a work around or will I need to create an *Insert Row* button with associated VBA to make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a macro to make changes on locked worksheets. For example:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
  'YOUR CODE HERE
Sheet1.Protect Password:="Secret"
End Sub
```

Please read this [article](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm) for more about running macros on protected worksheets.

If you need help on writing the macro, you can ask for help on our sister site [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: This has the problem of if the code breaks or the user interrupts the code, the sheet will be left unlocked.  If you use this approach it is probably best to use an `on error` to either force your code to continue running (`resume next`) or upon an error, stop running the code and just jump to the end of the code, and re-protect.

Answer (score -1):

When I click 'Protect Sheet...' I get a number of options for what I want to allow users to do, including 'Insert Rows.'

Am I misunderstanding your question or are you not seeing that?

Comment: I see the same options as you, but checking "Insert Rows" doesn't help - the table still refuses to add rows.

Comment: In this instance, "Insert rows" seems to refer to adding empty rows to the spread sheet (using right click -> insert, for example), not writing something in an already existing row.